# Changing TTextEdit to a right-to-left language doesn't change caret

Tags: delphi, devexpress, right-to-left, caret

I'm writing an application in Delphi XE3 that supports both English and Hebrew.

When I change the current language (with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>), while in edit mode of some text editor (TEdit etc), the caret (text cursor) icon doesn't change to the new direction like it does in editors in other known applications (Office, Chrome, etc).
For those of you who doesn't know the different caret icons possible, here are images of them:
[Left-to-right (English) caret icon](http://up380.siz.co.il/up3/t1fhokkgjmzz.png) and [Right-to-left (Hebrew) caret icon](http://up380.siz.co.il/up1/odjazzjnn3zk.png).

It's only when I change focus to another component, and then return to the previous editor in edit mode, that it displays the correct caret icon that corresponds to the current language direction.

Before using Delphi XE3, I've used Delphi 7 and it worked fine.
Also, I've tried DevExpress text editors, and they have the same problem.

Comment: There is no TTextEdit or TMultiEdit in Delphi 7 or Delphi XE3; what is it that you tried that "worked fine"? You talk about "edit mode"; what other modes are there in the controls you're dealing with?

Comment: Your'e right. I meant TEdit in Delphi VCL and TTextEdit/TcxMemo in DevExpress.
In short - every text editor.

Comment: A typical example why links to external sites are a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what might have worked in the past or what may have changed, but something like below should work.  It seems that `WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` is a slippery message and is almost impossible to catch reliably either by overriding `WndProc` or even hooking using `Application.HookMainWindow` (There's a decent article about it [here](http://www.siao2.com/2006/05/16/598980.aspx)).  Note also that this is just an example for the Hebrew keyboard - it won't catch all Right-to-Left keyboards (you'd obviously need to add them in if needed).

```
const HEBREW_KEYBOARD = $40D0000;
var gLangHook: HHOOK = 0;

function LangHookProc(Code: Integer; wParam: WPARAM; 
                                     lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;
begin
  if (Code = HC_ACTION) and 
     (PCWPStruct(lParam)^.message = WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE) then
  begin
    if (PCWPStruct(lParam)^.lParam and $FFFF0000) = HEBREW_KEYBOARD then
       Application.BiDiMode := bdRightToLeft
    else
       Application.BiDiMode := bdLeftToRight;
  end;
  Result := CallNextHookEx(gLangHook, Code, wParam, lParam);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  gLangHook := SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CALLWNDPROC, @LangHookProc, HInstance,
                                                            GetCurrentThreadId);
  if gLangHook = 0 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if gLangHook <> 0 then
  begin
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(gLangHook);
    gLangHook := 0;
  end;
end;
```

Here I've set the application's BiDiMode - if all children have `ParentBiDiMode := true` then all controls should switch to Right-to-Left mode.  Certainly you can handle this however you want - I think this is the hard part.

Comment: FIrst of all - Thank you for the reply :)  

I did have to struggle finding a way to catch the WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE message, but then I found CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE that works just fine.  
About the BiDiMode change - I've tryed to play with it beforehand, but it doesn't change the caret's direction, but only the alignment of the editor.

Comment: Wow...CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE is a lot easier.  It seemed like something the VCL wouldn't have left out but it's the first I hear of it.  Go figure.  In any case, at this point I'm not sure I understand what you mean anymore when you say *"it doesn't change the caret's direction"*.  Could you be more specific?

Comment: Yeah it's a bit hard to explain... So I'll try again with images :) Left-to-right (English) caret icon: [http://up380.siz.co.il/up3/t1fhokkgjmzz.png], Right-to-left (Hebrew) caret icon: [http://up380.siz.co.il/up1/odjazzjnn3zk.png]. And again, the problem is that when I change the language, the caret icon doesn't change immediately, but only when I change focus to another control, and then return to the previous editor.

Comment: @Saurye perhaps include those images with your main question, then. I'd never seen such a text input caret before (usually just a vertical line) and hadn't noticed that it had changed when switching to Hebrew.  In any case, I see it now - my english cursor is still just a vertical line but using the code above a focused edit box does switch alignment *and* immediately receives the correct RtL bidi caret (as in your second image - pointing to the left).  This is Delphi XE2, mind you.  Perhaps it is a bug in XE3?

Answer (score 0):

Whether it's a Delphi XE3 bug like @J... suggested, or a machine-specific bug, I encountered it nontheless.
I didn't find a clear solution, but a nice workaround instead.
NOTE: This solution works for DevExpress editors only, since the event is caught by TWinControl descendents.

Here is the code:

```
procedure OnChangeLanguageEvent(var Msg: TMessage); message CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE;

procedure TForm1.OnChangeLanguageEvent(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  Screen.ActiveControl.Perform(WM_KILLFOCUS,0,0);
  Screen.ActiveControl.Perform(WM_SETFOCUS,0,0);
  inherited;
end;
```

In this procedure I catch the event `CM_INPUTLANGCHANGE` and when I do, I sequently lose focus and regain focus of the currently active control. This simulates what I said earlier, that only when I change focus to another component, and then return to the previous editor in edit mode, that it displays the correct caret icon.
I don't really like this solution because it doesn't really solve anything, but it's fine for my needs.
Your welcome to suggest other ideas :)